# Mathematica: Getting rid of the "x ->" in FindInstance results

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have the following results:

```
a=FindInstance[2*b^2 + b^3 == b^4 + t && t < 10 && t > -1, {b, t}, 
  Integers, 20]
{{b -> -1, t -> 0}, {b -> 0, t -> 0}, {b -> 1, t -> 2}, {b -> 2, 
  t -> 0}}
```

How can I get rid of the "b->" and just get the array of b answers? I can get halfway there with:

```
a[[All,1]]
{b -> -1, b -> 0, b -> 1, b -> 2}
```

but how can I get to just:

```
{-1, 0, 1, 2}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I might be missing something from dreeves' answer, but the way I always believed you do this was simply by writing:

```
b /. a
```

There is an example of this in the "Basic Examples" section of [the documentation for the `Solve` function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html), which uses the same output style.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing.  I just assumed you had to explicitly map over the list of rules to get each value of `b`.  But, you're right, just `b /. a` knows to give a list of the b's for each rule in the list.  You win this round, Will Robertson!

Answer (score 3):

Though Will's answer is the canonical way to do it, I'll provide a few alternatives just for fun.

```
In[37]:= ans={{b -> -1, t -> 0},{b -> 0, t -> 0},{b -> 1, t -> 2},{b -> 2, t -> 0}};

In[38]:= Cases[ans, (b -> a_) :> a, Infinity]

Out[38]= {-1, 0, 1, 2}

In[39]:= ans[[All, 1]][[All, 2]]

Out[39]= {-1, 0, 1, 2}

In[40]:= ans /. {b -> a_, _} :> a

Out[40]= {-1, 0, 1, 2}

In[41]:= (ans /. Rule -> List)[[All, 1, 2]]

Out[41]= {-1, 0, 1, 2}
```